# Windows NTFS - Unable to change permissions of a file despite having all rights

Tags: windows-7, windows, ntfs

I'm trying to set/unset the Archive Bit of a file called **"Alice-file1.txt"**
This file is accessible from the following share

\\dhiwakar-pc\MixedData\AliceFold\Alice-file1.txt

I'm accessing this share with the domain credentials. These credentials work for all machines in the domain of which dhiwakar-pc is a part of.

I can't however set the Archive Bit even though "Everyone" has Full Control over the file.

[image]

Why is it like that ?

Comment: As `Deny` is always overriding `Allow`, please check your account didn't included a group with `Deny`

Comment: What is the error when you type `attrib +a Alice-file1.txt` from a windows command line? Is there an error message?

Comment: M:\MixedData\AliceFold>attrib +a "\\dhiwakar-pc\MixedData\AliceFold\Alice-file1.txt"
Access denied - \\dhiwakar-pc\MixedData\AliceFold\Alice-file1.txt  . If Access is Denied, how do I check from which group (of which my user account is a part of) I've inherited the Deny permission.